# Removing outlier from dataframe by filtering single column

Tags: python, dataframe, outliers, standard-deviation

I have a dataframe like this:

```
A    B   C  
1   10   121
5    6   122  
7    8   123  
9   10   124  
12  23   125
10  24   1500 
13  36   1600
```

By applying mean+/- 2std.deviation method to the column C, I wish to remove the outliers from C and filter the dataframe where I finally expect to get

```
A    B    C  
1   10   121
5    6   122  
7    8   123  
9   10   124  
12  23   125
```

This is my code:

```
target=df['C']
mean = target.mean()
sd = target.std()
lower_boundary = [x for x in target if (x < mean - 2 * sd)]
upper_boundary=  [x for x in target if (x > mean - 2 * sd)]

selected_df=df[(target==lower_boundary) & (target==upper_boundary)]
selected_df
```

But it shows

```
TypeError: invalid type comparison
```

error. Could you tell me where I make a mistake, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to do the operations on the target column to get a boolean series instead of a single boolean value:

```
target = df['C']
mean = target.mean()
sd = target.std()
selected_df = df[(target > mean - 2*sd) & (target < mean + 2*sd)]
```

Note that I fixed the `-` to a `+`. Note also that since the mean is about 530 and the standard deviation about 700, this does not actually remove anything (a good example of the mean being strongly influenced by outliers).

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue is:

> `(target==lower_boundary) & (target==upper_boundary)`

This evaluates to a boolean value, because you are doing a [bitwise and](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators)  of two boolean values.

You then try to index the data frame with a boolean key, which is failing.